# NUnit test runner - how to run test in location other than Program Files\Nunit 2.*.*

Tags: nunit, test-runner

Using NUnit test runner, when I run unit tests in project I'm working on, I'm getting following exception:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\App_Data' is denied.

This is because writing to C: requires administrator permissions, and test requires local database. I can run it as administrator, but I want to change execution location to another folder, but cannot find that setting. Is it possible to change execution location in NUnit?

**EDIT** It may be of significance that my test project is console app, not dll (for reasons beyond my influence).

Comment: What is NUnit test runner?  Usually I just run NUnit from the command line `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\nunit-x86-console d:\projects\tests.dll`

Comment: NUnit test runner = NUnit GUI ('C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\nunit.exe'). Console version also does not work for me, it has errors, but I cannot find xml with test results and cause of errors.

Comment: From the command line, you can use `/xml=\any path\results.xml` or the `/output` switch as well, to specify where to capture the log files.